# Can I Submit to Multiple Approval Steps in Parallel?

Tags: approval-process

I want to set up an approval process with 4 steps.  Each step has a different criteria and a different approval queue.  Currently, when I Submit for Approval, it only steps Step 1.  When Step 1 is approved, it moves to Step 2 and so forth.  Can I configure the system where when you submit for approval it submits all 4 Approval Steps at once?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This still isn't possible using standard Salesforce approvals. There are some tools on the AppExchange that do it. They work around standard approvals, though, and have their own mechanism/datamodel. E.g. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008Y8xfEAC and https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMcp7UAD

Also Salesforce CPQ approvals can do this (even on custom objects).